# Непонятная высота блоков в Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В Internet Explorer у блоков появляется непонятный отступ снизу.

В остальных браузерах нормально.

Код блоков и картинку прилагаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4">
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <a href=cups.php>
            <img src="cupst.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-footer py-0">
                <b style="font-size: 12px">Кубки Standart</b>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какая версия IE?

Comment: 11. Подозреваю что дело в том, что размер картинки 400х400. Бутстрап свое дело сделал и уменьшил изображение, но IE оставляет место якобы для нее.

Comment: ну попробуйте установить, как пример, display:inline-block; для родителя изображения

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо.